# gcloud appengine go app crashes without any errors

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, runtime-error, gcloud

I deployed my Go application to gcloud Appengine. This application is connected with Auth0 for our user management. After a view time somebody is triggering a call which is communicating with Auth0 and the Backend is crashing without a Panic, error nothing and restarts after a minute or longer.

Did somebody have the same issue?

This is my config of the app in the appengine:

```
app.yml


runtime: go
env: flex
instance_class: B2

runtime_config:
  operating_system: 'ubuntu22'
  runtime_version: '1.21'

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 600

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: cloud-instance
  has_docker_image: 'true'
  module_yaml_path: app.yaml

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

I tried to write debug messages inside the calls of resty to auth0 but nothing is logged.

I updated the timeout duration of the api to 700 seconds.

Comment: Which logs have your checked?

Comment: I checked the log output of the App-Engine in the Log-Explorer